# How to redirect to another page

Tags: php

Want to fetch a number from a database and use that number to direct to a new page

```
$sql4="SELECT `level_crossed` FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myuser' and password='$mypass'";
$result4=mysql_query($sql4);
$disp4=mysql_fetch_assoc($result4);

header('Location: quiz".$disp4.".php');
```

Level crossed is of integer type. I want to redirect the current page to quiz1 or quiz2 or quiz 3 page depending on the value stored in `level_crossed` attribute.

But it is unable to redirect. URL coming up as http://treasurehunt.faltutalk.com/quiz%22.$result.%22.php

Comment: header('Location: quiz'.$disp4.'.php');

Comment: `$disp4['level_crossed ']`.

Comment: But I have used double quotes in "$disp4"

Comment: But your single quotes are not escaped. You have just put a concate string, nothing else.

Comment: after using '$disp4' errored URL : http://treasurehunt.faltutalk.com/quiz.'Array'.php it is showing array instead of going to that page

Comment: [`mysql_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php): Returns an associative array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row 

so it should like`$disp4['some_field']`

Answer (score 0):

the string you use in the header function call has mixed quotes and thus it's wrong. You can choose one of the following:

first of all, get a normal string:

```
$str = $disp4['level_crossing'];
```

then choose:

```
header('Location: quiz'.$str.'.php');
```

or

```
header("Location: quiz$disp4.php");
```

or even

```
header("Location: quiz".$str.".php");
```

next time, double check your quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to `header("Location: quiz{$disp4['level_crossed']}.php");`

Comment: And may I know if I want to add 1 with the level_crossed value then how should I write .

Comment: Add this line before it `$disp4['level_crossed'] += 1`, you must learn some basic statement first

Answer (score 0):

Swap out the double quotes for single quotes